# Can I use a URL for EQA?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm doing a project that requires use of EQA, but the only source is a website and I don't own it, is there a possible way to bruteforce/workaround a url into EQA?

Comment: What does EQA mean?

Comment: Extractive Question Answering

Comment: Thought I could help but I have no idea what that is in relation to DF, sorry. :) I googled it and it may have something to do with the KB feature but we abandoned that for being buggy and terrible.  Hope someone else can help you out.